# Get list of titles from xml files

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to get titles of xml files from a folder call "bugs".

My code:

```
    public virtual List<IBug> FillBugs()
    {
        string folder = xmlStorageLocation + "bugs" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

        List<IBug> bugs = new List<IBug>();

        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            var q = from b in bugs
                    select new IBug
                    {
                        Title = b.Title,
                        Id = b.Id,
                    };

            return q.ToList();
        }

        return bugs;
    }
```

But I'm not geting out the titles from all the xml files in the folder "bugs".

---

the biggest problem is to get eatch files to singel string and not string[].

Comment: Are you getting all of the files and not getting the correct results from them, or are you not even getting all of the expected files?

Answer (score 2):

Your code as written doesn't make any sense.  Perhaps you meant something more like this:

```
public virtual List<IBug> FillBugs()
{
    // is this actually correct or did you mix up the concatenation order?
    // either way, I suggest Path.Combine() instead

    string folder = xmlStorageLocation + "bugs" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

    List<IBug> bugs = new List<IBug>();

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.xml",
        SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        // i guess IBug is not actually an interface even though it starts 
        // with "I" since you made one in your code

        bugs.Add(new IBug {
            Title = file, Id = 0 /* don't know where you get an ID */ });
    }

    return bugs;
}
```

Comment: The title and id are in eatch xml file, and i wan't to get out the title and id from eatch xml file to a list

Comment: Then within your "foreach" you need to open the file and parse out the information you need, and then add it to your collection as shown.

Answer (score 1):

"from b in bugs" selects from an empty list. you need to initialize bugs from the file at the start of your foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a backslash (Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) between xmlStorageLocation and "bugs"?

Comment: No i don't because xmlStorageLOcation include a Path.DirectorySeparatorChar

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `file` in your loop anywhere - Is that correct or did you miss to push it into the collection?

Comment: i miss to push it into the collection,